# Do I need to use the spread operator when using useState hook on object when updating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started learning about hooks, and according to the official docs on [Using Multiple State Variables](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-using-multiple-state-variables), we find the following line:

> However, unlike `this.setState` in a class, updating a state variable always replaces it instead of merging it.

So, if I understand correctly, this mean I don't need to use the spread operator for updating the state?

Comment: You need to explain your question a little more and maybe include some examples. You never *have* to use the spread operator to update state. I'm guessing you're referring to when you need to clone objects or arrays and ensure you aren't mutating?

Comment: yes, actually, yea

Comment: Then yes, like answers have already said, you still need to make sure you don't mutate state, nothing has changed in that regard

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You still don't want to mutate state. So if your state is an object, you'll want to create a new object and set with that. This may involve spreading the old state. For example:

```
const [person, setPerson] = useState({ name: 'alice', age: 30 });

const onClick = () => {
  // Do this:
  setPerson(prevPerson => {
    return { 
      ...prevPerson, 
      age: prevPerson.age + 1 
    }
  })
  // Not this:
  //setPerson(prevPerson => {
  //  prevPerson.age++;
  //  return prevPerson;
  //});
}
```

That said, using hooks you often no longer need your state to be an object, and can instead use useState multiple times. If you're not using objects or arrays, then copying is not needed, so spreading is also not needed.

```
const [name, setName] = useState('alice');
const [age, setAge] = useState(30);

const onClick = () => {
  setAge(prevAge => prevAge + 1);
}
```

Comment: This is a good way to put it - break up each property of what would have been your state object into their own separate variables.  I was always curious what people do when they find they need a ton of state variables - how to avoid the mess?  Is it better to use a class component with a state object at that point?

Comment: @SethLutske There's nothing stopping you from using an object in a `useState` hook, so no need to go back to classes for it. You just don't *have* to now. You can keep things separated by concerns. Sometimes that makes sense as a bunch of single values, sometimes as an object. Depends on the use-case.

Comment: ty sir, all of u, this got confusing, @SethLutske ur answer is good as well, ty.

Comment: While this answer isn't wrong, it doesn't address what the question is quoting specifically, which is [the default `setState` behaviour in class components, where the new state objects are automatically shallow merged](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), thus not needing to always spread the state object. The new behaviour is correctly highlighted in [Seth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60156935/1218980).

Comment: Is the arrow function really needed? In the answer by @SethLutske it seems as though it will also work without passing an arrow function.

Comment: Its not needed, but sometimes comes in handy.  For example, if your are passing your setter function down to a child component as a prop, its nice to use the array function because it gives you access to the state variable its setting without explcitly having to pass that down *also* as a prop.  It may also help make sure you're not using stale state values if you're calling the setter within nested closures, which may have closed in old state values.

Comment: If I have multiple value in the state for example ```useState({ name: 'alice', age: 30 },{ name: 'mike', age: 31 });```, how do I update only where name===mike?

Answer (score 23):

What it means is that if you define a state variable like this:

```
const [myThings, changeMyThings] = useState({cats: 'yes', strings: 'yellow', pizza: true })
```

Then you do something like `changeMyThings({ cats: 'no' })`, the resulting state object will just be `{ cats: 'no' }`.  The new value is not merged into the old one, it is just replaced.  If you want to maintain the whole state object, you *would* want to use the spread operator:

```js
changeMyThings({ ...myThings, cats: 'no' })
```

This would give you your original state object and only update the one thing you changed.

Comment: Same was my thought, but I was in need of confirmation, this is the solution, when you don't want to replace the state with useState hook, so for keeping the old ones' and bringing change only in the desired one then this is useful technique. By ones' I mean the items in object.

Comment: Whats the difference between using the spread operator on myThings VS doing a spread operator on prevMyThings?

Comment: @KevinOrriss it depends.  Sometimes you are calling your setState function inside of some other callback, where the value of `myThings` might be stale.  In that case, calling `changeMyThings(prevMyThings => ({ ...prevMyThings, cats: 'no' }))` is safer in that it always uses the current value of the state variable, and should never use a stale value.  In my answer, depending on the context of where the setState call is run, you may be working with stale values.