# React How do I extract data from a form when triggering onSubmit event?

Tags: reactjs

I am messing around with Riot's API that allows getting information of a player by the player's name. I am trying to get an API key (I only got a 24 hour key) and the target player's name from users' input.

```
export function PlayerSearch() {
    function handlesubmit(e) {
      console.log(e.target);
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    return (
    <div className='player'>
    <div className='inputfield'>
    <form onSubmit={handlesubmit} method='GET' autoComplete="off">
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="key">Your API key:</label>
        <input 
          placeholder='Your API key'
          onFocus={(e)=>{e.target.placeholder=''}}
          type="text" 
          id="key"
          name="key" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="name">Player name:</label>
        <input 
          placeholder='Player name' 
          onFocus={(e)=>{e.target.placeholder=''}} 
          type="text" 
          id="name" 
          name="name" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type='submit' />
      </div> 
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    );
}
```

And I got this in the console:

[image]

So how exactly do I extract the two inputs from the form?

In addition, is it possible that I can call another component and pass data as props to handle the submitted data so that the code is cleaner?

Comment: Have you tried reading the react documentation? https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: I agree with @PAB following the documentation is best if you're interested in learning and low level control.  If you're building a serious application, take a look at https://formik.org/

Comment: @PAB Yes, I have looked into the documentation and tried using useState but failed. Turns out that you have to spread out the data with `...` syntax. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a state to store your inputs:

```js
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ key: "", name: "" });
```

Then you need a function that gets called `onChange` of your input fields to update your state:

```js
const onChange = (event) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
};
```

And you need to pass that function to your `input` `onChange` property:

```html
<input
    placeholder="Your API key"
    onFocus={(e) => {
      e.target.placeholder = "";
    }}
    type="text"
    name="key"
    value={formData.key}
    onChange={onChange}
/>
```

Then you can access the state in your `handleSubmit`:

```js
function handlesubmit(e) {
    console.log(formData);
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

[image: Edit stoic-night-de8wjx]

Comment: Thanks! You really helped a lot! I didn't even know that '...' syntax is a thing. One more question though, why do we need to use squared brackets in `setFormData({ ...formData, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });` for the event.target.name? I just saw examples that doesn't use it like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60156883/do-i-need-to-use-the-spread-operator-when-using-usestate-hook-on-object-when-upd) when looking the spread operator up. Sorry if I am asking dumb questions, I am still very new to this.

Comment: If you want to use a variable as a key in an object, you need to use the square bracket syntax to define it as a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer?retiredLocale=de#computed_property_names).