# React Native - FlatList value not updated when data has changed

Tags: reactjs, list, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

I am using a FlatList which has cards like any social media app. Each card is a sepearte component.And you can add to favourites to every card. When I am updation value for favorites on card the list does not update at all. I got latest array but list shows with older favourites value.

**Code for updating favourites on card component**

```
const updatebookMark = () => {
let newArray = [...feedArray];

let id = item.cardId;
const index = newArray.findIndex(object => {
  return object.cardId === id;
});

if (index !== -1) {
  newArray[index].bookmarked = bookmarkSelected;

  addFeedsToLocalDB(newArray);
}
}
```

**Adding to Local DB function**

```
 const addFeedsToLocalDB = async cardsArray => {
await AsyncStorage.removeItem('feedArray');
await AsyncStorage.setItem('feedArray', JSON.stringify(cardsArray));

 setFeedArray([]);
setFeedArray(cardsArray);
 };
```

**Here setFeedArray is state that I am updating using Context API**

If I update **setFeedArray([]);** by making it null and then adding value to it then list updated with the latest value but it cause each time refresh on the list and the list to flickered.

Now Flatlist code:

**Get Item from local storage when data changed**

```
useEffect(() => {
getCardsFromLocalDB();

}, [feedArray]);

const getCardsFromLocalDB = async () => {
const feedCards = await AsyncStorage.getItem('feedArray');

if (JSON.parse(feedCards).length > 0) {

  setCount(count + 1);
  setFeedCards(feedArray);

  }
 }
 };
```

And in Flatlist I have used **extraData to update value and I used count for that**

```
 <FlatList
        extraData={count}
        data={feedCards}
        scrollEnabled={true}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => (
          <RenderCard
            item={item}
            navigation={navigation}
            index={index}
            managePost={false}
            isPaymentReport={false}
            isBookmark={false}
            previewMode={false}
            isPinnedPost={false}
            isPaymentExplorer={false}
          />
        )}
        numColumns={1}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          paddingBottom: height * 0.1,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        }}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.05}
        onScrollBeginDrag={() => setLoadingMore(true)}
        onEndReached={handleOnEndReached}
        ListFooterComponent={() => loadingMore && <ListFooterComponent />}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={refreshing}
            onRefresh={() => onRefresh()}
            tintColor={Colors.light.black}
          />
        }
      />
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Put your local storage data(feedCards) in the useState and then it will update. Every time you update your state, you can update your local storage, too. In order for component to rerender, state or props need to be changed.

Comment: I have used state for that which is  const [feedCards, setFeedCards] = useState([]); but still not working

Comment: Do you use memo in your RenderCard component?

Comment: No, I am not using memo in RenderCard

Comment: Oke, if you want you can create a snack -> https://snack.expo.dev/ , with it it will be way easier to fix this problem. Create it with fake data, without local storage, try to reproduce the problem

Comment: It will be too lengthy to do that

Comment: If possible could you please help me here.

Comment: It can be connected in the way you are setting bookmarked to true/false. You should use spread operator when changing object state. I cant now without all the code. Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60156883/do-i-need-to-use-the-spread-operator-when-using-usestate-hook-on-object-when-upd

Comment: Thankyou so much for this link but I have changed value like  newArray[index].bookmarked = bookmarkSelected . How can I implement the same according to above link

Comment: if (index !== -1) {
      // let item = newArray[index].bookmarked;

      setFeedArray(feed => {
        feed[index].bookmarked = bookmarkSelected;

        return [...feed];
      });


I have tried this too data updated but list not updated

Comment: Here is a working expo, how to do it. I am toggling only the first one, but you can change id in the function -> https://snack.expo.dev/HClcJoNPp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250615/discussion-between-deepanshi-gupta-and-alija-fajic).

Answer (score 0):

just change this

```
 const addFeedsToLocalDB = async cardsArray => {
await AsyncStorage.removeItem('feedArray');
await AsyncStorage.setItem('feedArray', JSON.stringify(cardsArray));

 setFeedArray([]);
setFeedArray([...cardsArray]);
 };
```